# Meaning of mathematical notation for summation with two variables.

Tags: notation

Is the notation

$$ \sum_{x, y}  $$

mathematically equivalent to:

$$ \sum_{x}\sum_{y}$$

Comment: Usually, yes. ${}{}$

Comment: Yes, unless the order of the summation makes a different to convergence.  (And this can happen only for infinite series.)

Comment: The comma can also be omitted.

Comment: Perfect, thanks guys